# Visual Studio registration takes me to a 404.htm

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, registration

I have a Windows 8.1, and I just downloaded the VisualStudio 2012 express for Windows Desktop.

A message shows up saying:

```
"This product will expire in 30 day(s)
Registration is required for continued use of Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop"
```

Then I have a disabled button saying "Next", an editbox where I should enter my registration code (probably) and a link "Register online".
If I click the "Register online" link then I am taken to the login page, where I authenticate myself just fine.
And then I am redirected to another page "http://www.microsoft.com/404.htm"
that says:

```
"We are sorry, the page you requested cannot be found.     
The URL may be misspelled or the page you're looking for is no longer available."
```

- The link opens in InternetExplorer. I made it default just for this to work
- I disabled my AVAST antivirus so that would nopt be an issue.
- I wrote to support but who knows when they will answer, and I need this to work NOW.
- In Internet Explorer I disabled Protected mode, still no result.
  (of course all of the above were done after I tried to make it work directly without any tweaks)

What should I do?

I must attend a Codility interview in a few hours, and I need my IDE to work, so I would not have to rely on their online IDE that lacks many things.

Comment: Thisis not a programmation question...

Comment: This appears to be the correct link once you sign in (first Google result for "visual studio 2012 register online") https://profile.microsoft.com/RegSysProfileCenter/wizard.aspx?wizid=2525f0ba-d85f-4730-bd75-e1299f83e666&lcid=1033

Comment: Maybe it's time to upgrade to a better and free version of [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This issue does not have anything to do with your browser, or your computer.

A 404 error simply means that the page that you are trying to access does not exist on Microsoft's servers. Therefore the problem is not with you, but either with Microsoft, or with the software you are using.

You could either search for the registration page on Microsoft's website, or maybe the version of 'Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop' is out of date and is sending you to an old link. <strike>You could try re-downloading it.</strike> *EDIT: Don't re-download it, see below!*

If the worst comes to the worst, you could always try using a more recent - and probably better - version of Visual Studio (I use the 2015 version, and it's free!).

**EDIT:**

I searched for a couple of minutes and came up with this link:
[profile.microsoft.com/RegSysProfileCenter/](http://profile.microsoft.com/RegSysProfileCenter/)

You will have to sign in first, and then it will take you to the "Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop" registration page that you want.